# How to get $[(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}u](x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}\vert x-y \vert )}{4\pi \vert x-y \vert}u(y)dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

> We have $-\Delta+\lambda$ is invertible on $C_{c}^{\infty}$ and using Fourier transform, then $(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}u$ is in Schwartz space for $u\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Using Green's function,
>   $$[(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}u](x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}\vert x-y \vert )}{4\pi \vert x-y \vert}u(y)dy. \ (*)$$

How to get the (*)? Moreover, we have 
$$[V(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}u](x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\vert V(x) \vert \frac{\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}\vert x-y \vert )}{4\pi \vert x-y \vert}u(y)dy, \ (**)$$

where the kernel is Hilbert-Schmidt kernel
$$K_{\lambda}(x,y)=\vert V(x) \vert \frac{\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}\vert x-y \vert )}{4\pi \vert x-y \vert}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^6).$$

---

Since $K_{\lambda}(x,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^6)$, $V(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}$ is compact.(From $V$ is $(-\Delta)$-compact.

Comment: Looks a bit like one should apply Fourier analysis?

Comment: Are you sure you're working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I have no idea.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Sure

Comment: Using the Fourier transform of a Guassian, 
\begin{align}
    (-\Delta+\lambda I)^{-1}f &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{|\xi|^2+\lambda}\left(\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot y}dy\right)e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi \\
  &=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-i\xi\cdot (y-x)}}{|\xi|^2+\lambda}d\xi dy 
\end{align}
I don't see a way to get the stated form for the kernel shown above.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824681/how-to-show-that-v-cdot-delta-lambda-1-is-compact Similar to this way?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I try to show $V(\cdot)(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}$ is compact. I need to prove it is Hilbert-Schmidt operator which is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having problems with recent modifications to the editor on this site. Long solutions cause my browser to slow to crawl. So I did this outside of the editor, and pasted as a picture.

[image]

Comment: If you post the source to pastebin or some other publicly reachable site, I can edit your answer to include it. Just tag me in a comment with the link included.

Comment: @Andrew : I did it in Latex. Every keystroke was causing the screen to refresh, and it could no longer keep up at some time, and Microsoft Edge started getting confused and starting interpreting characters as something else entirely. Very strange. MathJax is broken on this site for me.

Comment: @Andrew : I made several corrections to the initial post. It should be correct now.

Comment: I understand, I was only suggesting that I could add the latex version to your post if you sent me the source somehow. I use Firefox mostly, and MathJax is usable for me.

Comment: @Andrew : I'm not sure what has happened. Regardless, I appreciate your kind, generous offer.