# Suppose $V\in L^2({\mathbb{R}^3})$, how to show that $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \Vert V(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}\Vert =0$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

> Let $\mathscr{H}=L^2({\mathbb{R}^3})$ be Hilbert space, suppose $V\in L^2({\mathbb{R}^3}), \lambda>0$, show that $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \Vert V(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}\Vert =0$$

I try to use this method [How to get $[(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}u](x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}\vert x-y \vert )}{4\pi \vert x-y \vert}u(y)dy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814469/how-to-get-delta-lambda-1ux-int-mathbbr3-frac-exp-sqrt-l) But I do not understand the reasons.
It would imply $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta+V)=[0,\infty)$, which using the Wely's theorem:

> Suppose $A$ is a self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space, $B$ is symmetric if $B$ is $A-$compact then $$ \sigma_{ess}(A+B)=\sigma_{ess}(A).$$

Comment: I have no idea what the notation $V(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}$ means. You can prove that the norm of $(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}V$ tends to zero using Plancherel.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Maybe you could understand $\dfrac{V}{-\Delta+\lambda}$？ Is it right? But I think this is same as $(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}V$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What is the fourier transform of $(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}V$？

Comment: $(|\xi|^2+\lambda)^{-1}\hat f(\xi)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is it $\mathscr{F}((\Delta+\lambda)^{-1})V)=(\vert \xi \vert ^2 +\lambda)^{-1}\mathscr{F}(V)$?

Comment: Yes - II wrote $f$ instead of $V$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since $\Vert \mathscr{F}((\Delta+\lambda)^{-1} V)\Vert =\vert (\vert \xi \vert ^2+\lambda)^{-1}\vert \Vert \mathscr{F}(V)\Vert$ . As $\lambda \to 0$, we have $\Vert \mathscr{F}((\Delta+\lambda)^{-1} V)\Vert  \to 0$, this imply $\Vert (\Delta+\lambda)^{-1} V\Vert  \to 0$. Is it your meaning?

Comment: No, you can't factor out the $(|\xi|^2+\lambda)^{-1}$ because it's not a constant. But $|(\xi^2+\lambda)^{-1}|\le 1/|\lambda|$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks a lot!